# Firebase realtime database security rule get child name

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Is there a way i get the an child's name ? The structure is like so:

```
appointment-
           |- "here_is_some_date"-
                                 |-"some_user_id"-
                                                 |-details about it
```

I need to define a rule for who can read the "appointments" but i am not sure on how to get the date's name so i can get to the UID. This is what i've tried:

```
"appointments": {
        ".read": "data.child(data.val()).child(auth.uid).val() === auth.uid"
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to read the value of a child node in Firebase security rules is if you know the exact path from the current node (where the rule is defined) to the child node.

So if you know both the date, and the UID (which you definitely do), you can read the value of the child node with:

```
"appointments": {
  ".read": "data.child('here_is_some_date').child('some_user_id').val() === auth.uid"
}
```

But there is no way to have a wildcard in this path. It's a bit hard to say what use-case you're exactly trying to implement, but if it's "allowing a user to read the appointment dates for which they have an appointment", then that would require an additional, inverted data structure:

```
"user_appointment_dates": {
  "uid1": {
    "date1": true // or a more complete structure with the actual appointments
  }
}
```